# How does Tweetdeck manages to keep working according to twitter API limits?

Tags: twitter

According to API [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline), there are consumption rates limits per app and even per user. How could TweetDeck manage to keep streaming timelines and tweets getting over window limits?

Comment: TweetDeck belongs to Twitter. Doesn't make sense for them to put limits on their own app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TweetDeck is owned by Twitter and is accessing an API called the Firehose that has no rate limits.

Comment: But according to this article Tweetdeck is also affected by the twitter API limits: http://simplebutgood.net/tweetdeck-refresh-streaming-api-limits/